# Inplace inside Tree : how to save the modified TreeNode?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, tree, inplace-editing

I'm using Primefaces 4.0 and I have a `<p:tree>` with editable node labels :

```xml
<p:tree id="treeSingle" dynamic="true"
    value="#{treeController.treeRoot}" var="node"
    selectionMode="single" selection="#{treeController.selectedNode}">
  <p:treeNode>
    <p:inplace editor="true" event="dblclick">
      <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{treeController.onSaveNodeLabel}" update="@this" />
      <p:inputText value="#{node.label}" />
    </p:inplace>
  </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

What I want to do is saving the #{node.label} value when it is modified by the user.

The `listener="#{treeController.onSaveNodeLabel}"` calls a method which should save the modified `TreeNode` label. So I have created this method in my `treeController` class :

```java
public void onSaveNodeLabel(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    logger.info("onSaveNodeLabel");
    Inplace inplace = (Inplace)event.getSource();
    UITreeNode uiTreeNode = (UITreeNode) inplace.getParent();
    // What next?
}
```

**Problem** : the `AjaxBehaviorEvent` allows me to access the [org.primefaces.component.tree.UITreeNode](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/4.0/org/primefaces/component/tree/UITreeNode.html) but not the [org.primefaces.model.TreeNode](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/4.0/org/primefaces/model/class-use/TreeNode.html) which holds my data. Is there a solution to get to `TreeNode` from `AjaxBehaviorEvent`? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to save the value of #{node.label}, that's it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'll update my question.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the node value to your method? like this:      #{treeController.onSaveNodeLabel(node.label)} and then receive it in your method and do whatever you want

Comment: You're welcome ! Please, mark as answer to be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just send the node.label as a parameter to your function:

`#{treeController.onSaveNodeLabel(node.label)}`

So, in your web page:

```
<p:inplace editor="true" event="dblclick">
  <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{treeController.onSaveNodeLabel(node.label)}" update="@this" />
  <p:inputText value="#{node.label}" />
</p:inplace>
```

And in your bean:

```
public void onSaveNodeLabel(String nodeLabel) {
    //
}
```

Comment: In fact what I did is more like `onSaveNodeLabel(node.id, node.label)`.

Comment: Nice! You could also use `onSaveNodeLabel(node)` and get the node properties in the bean :)

Comment: You're right, this is simpler. It should be noted, though, that the `var="node"` attribute inside `<p:tree>` doesn't contain a reference to the TreeNode object but a reference to the data contained in the TreeNode (accessible by `TreeNode.getData()`). Hence, I have renamed my variable `treeNodeData` instead of `node`.